# Why is angular written twice when requiring it as a Bower component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, bower, commonjs

I've seen this syntax for requiring Bower components (like Angular) into a project:

`require('angular/angular');`

I'm curious as to why it's written as 'angular/angular' instead of just 'angular'.

This project used Browserify with `transform: debowerify` in the options and I suspected that has something to do with it:

from Gruntfile.js

```
...
    browserify: {
      dev: {
        options: {
          transform: ['debowerify']
        },
        src: ['<%= project.alljs %>'],
        dest: 'build/js/client-bundle.js'
      },
    },
...
```

Comment: Bower typically groups projects this way, which is handy when a single project has many subprojects or components.

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly, ```require('angular');``` would also work, but it would include additional components that I might not need, correct?

Comment: I don't believe that it would work (though you are free to try it and see if it does or not). What I was saying is simply that there is an extra "angular" folder inserted so that it is possible to install related projects under a common parent (e.g.  "angular/routes", "angular/i18n", "angular/loader", etc.). I don't know that angular, specifically, takes advantage of this structure... but other projects often do.

Comment: I understand now. My confusion was with the fact that NPM only made you write out the package name eg ```require('moment');``` and it would navigate the tree for you. It appears that Bower makes you navigate the tree to get the file you're looking for.